# Ruby Number Range Regular Expression Between 1-200

Tags: ruby, regex, range, gsub

I'm trying to implement a number range using the gsub function between 1-200, but I couldn't find any good examples. I'm implementing a bbcode system where a user should be able to enter something like

1. `[size=80]Hello world[/size]` => Valid
2. `[size=200]Hello world[/size]` => Valid
3. `[size=201]Hello world[/size]` => Invalid

This is currently what I have being fed into the gsub method and it accepts anything between 1-999:

```
\[size=(\d{1,3})\](.+?)\[\/size\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this: `/\[size=(?:200|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d?)\](.+?)\[\/size\]/`

my testing program:

```
if '[size=80]Hello world[/size]' =~ /\[size=(?:200|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d?)\](.+?)\[\/size\]/ 
    puts 'valid'
else    
    puts 'invalid'
end        

if '[size=200]Hello world[/size]' =~ /\[size=(?:200|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d?)\](.+?)\[\/size\]/     
    puts 'valid'
else    
    puts 'invalid'
end          

if '[size=201]Hello world[/size]' =~ /\[size=(?:200|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d?)\](.+?)\[\/size\]/     
    puts 'valid'
else    
    puts 'invalid'
end
```

output:

```
valid
valid
invalid
```

Comment: That was a speedy answer, I see you're aptly named :)